# How to cancel an incoming POST request in NodeJS sending a 4XX but without receiving the entire data?

Tags: node.js, http, post, request

A client can upload files to my NodeJS server. I want to make sure the client does not abuse the server and upload files that are too large. Therefore I want to cancel the request as soon as I detect a problem, but also return a meaningful status code and response to the client. Assume that the user uploads a file that is 100 MB large, but my server has a maximum file size of 10 MB.

If I do

```
req.socket.destroy()
```

the client will get a SocketException if in Java, or a canceled request in the browser.

Is there a better way to send an elegant response and in the same time avoid receiving the entire 100 MB file?

Comment: Not a NodeJS solution, but consider using [Nginx](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-413-request-entity-too-large/)

Comment: What happens if you do `req.connection.destroy()`? It there any difference?

Answer (score 0):

From [413 Request Entity Too Large](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

> The server is refusing to process a request because the request entity
>   is larger than the server is willing or able to process. The server
>   MAY close the connection to prevent the client from continuing the
>   request.

So according to the protocol you should first send a 413 response and then close the connection.

Try

```
res.writeHead(413, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('10mb max.');
```

Comment: I think that you would have to read the entire response this way, unless the content-length header is specified in the request, what I doubt will happen for sure..